# Why is my AI acting strange in a game of tic-tac-toe?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

The organisation of the data for the game of tic-tac-toe is simple.

There is an array that contains a lot of HTML `button`s.
The program remembers if a button is used by using the `isUsed` array.
It checks what image to display on the button using the `isX` Boolean.
The program contains a list of winning combinations that are available to everyone using `freeWins` array. When a human picks 5, all the winning combos containing 5 are moved to an array called `yourWins`. Then, the positions owned by the human will be replaced from `yourWins`.

### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title> 1Player </title>
    <style>
        #stage{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .square{
            user-select : none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;

            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: gray;
            position: absolute;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="stage">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        const ROWS = 3;
        const COLS = 3;
        const GAP = 10;
        const SIZE = 64;
        var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

        var lotOfButtons = [];
        var isUsed = [false,false,false,false,
                     false,false,false,false,false];


        var myPositions = "";
        var yourPositions = "";
        var youPicked = "";
        var iPicked = "";
        var isX = true;
        var isFirstMove = true;


        var myWins = [];
        var yourWins = [];
        var freeWins = ["123","159","147",
                        "258",
                        "369","357",
                        "456",
                        "789"];

        prepareBoard();
        stage.addEventListener("click",clickHandler,false);


        function prepareBoard(){ //Prepare the board on which the users will play.
            for(var row = 0;row<ROWS;row++){ // Prepare the rows.
            for(var col = 0;col < COLS;col++){ //Prepare the columns.
                var square = document.createElement("button"); //Prepare the button which represents a square.
                square.setAttribute("class","square"); //Make it a square 'officially'.
                stage.appendChild(square); //Add the square to the play area..
                lotOfButtons.push(square); //Keep a record of squares.
                square.style.left = col * (SIZE+GAP) + "px"; //Properly set the horizontal spacing.
                square.style.top = row * (SIZE+GAP) + "px"; //Properly set the vertical spacing.
            }
            }
        }

        function clickHandler(event){
            var index = lotOfButtons.indexOf(event.target);
            if(index=== -1 || isX === false){
                return;
            }
            isX = false;
            isUsed[index] = true;
            event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/X.png)";
            yourMove(index+1);
        }

        function yourMove(someIndex){
            console.log("Finding Human Winning Moves::: ");
            yourWins = findWinnindMoves(yourWins,someIndex);
            console.log(yourWins);
            console.log("Clearing Human Owned Positions::: ");
            yourWins = clearOwnedPositions(yourWins,someIndex);
            console.log(yourWins + "\n");

            myMove();
        }

        function myMove(){
            var isFifthSquareUsed = isFiveUsed();
            if(isFifthSquareUsed === false){ //Is fifth square used ?? --- NO!
                var selectedSquare = lotOfButtons[4];
                selectedSquare.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/O.PNG)";
                isUsed[4] = true;
                isFirstMove = false;
                isX = true;

                console.log("Finding AI Winning Moves::: ");
                myWins = findWinnindMoves(myWins,4);
                console.log(myWins);
                console.log("Clearing AI Owned Positions::: ");
                myWins = clearOwnedPositions(myWins,4);
                console.log(myWins + "\n");


            }else if(isFifthSquareUsed && isFirstMove){ //Is fifth square used ?? --- YES, but it is first move.
                //TODO add logic
            }else{ //Some random square has already been chosen. Now it is time to use strategy.
                //TODO add logic
            }
        }

        function findWinnindMoves(winsArray,someIndex){//using which combination can a user or AI win ?
            for(var i = 0;i<freeWins.length;i++){
                if(freeWins[i].indexOf(someIndex) != -1){
                    winsArray.push(freeWins[i]);
                    i--;
                    freeWins.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            return winsArray;
        }

        function clearOwnedPositions(winsArray,someIndex){ //Reduce the number of squares needed to get triplets.
            for(var i=0;i<winsArray.length;i++){
                if(winsArray[i].indexOf(someIndex) != -1){
                    winsArray[i] = winsArray[i].replace(someIndex,"");
                }
            }
            return winsArray;
        }

        function isFiveUsed(){ //Is AI able to get the center square ?
            return isUsed[4];
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

### Problem

The determination of the winning moves for the user and the AI works properly if I click the second or the third row and **not on first row**.

### Output on Row 2

```
Finding Human Winning Moves:::
["147", "456"]
Clearing Human Owned Positions:::
17,56
Finding AI Winning Moves:::
["147", "456"]
Clearing AI Owned Positions:::
17,56
```

### Output on Row 1

```
Finding Human Winning Moves:::
["123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"]
Clearing Human Owned Positions:::
23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23
Finding AI Winning Moves:::
[]
Clearing AI Owned Positions:::
```

---

Also, after clearing the owned squares the array brackets are gone.
**Why are the two problems happening?**

Comment: Just the mere positioning of the call to `splice` is the problem. move it one line up and `i--` down and the problem goes :/

Comment: Using `splice` with normal (incrementing) loops messes up looping because items will be skipped over - you seemed to have counteracted that with the `i--`. Try looping backwards (fixes this problem) and you won't have to deal with modifying `i` **inside** the loop.

Comment: @Ian Why are the brackets disappearing when I replace the owned squares ???

Answer (score 1):

To Answer your second question about the Arrays, You cannot initialize  a blank Array and at the same time `.push()` in the same area. Every time you run the JavaScript it re-creates the Array and that means goodbye to the stuff you are putting into it. Maybe you should initialize the Array outside a function and put the rest of the code inside the function. As for your game AI, I am not entirely sure. Hope this helps somewhat.